# Extract the highest number out of a row of strings

Tags: sql-server

I have data in a #temp_table like this:

```
   SCORM_VARNAME
1) cmi.interactions.0.id
2) cmi.interactions.1.id
3) cmi.interactions.10.id
4) cmi.interactions.5.id
5) cmi.interactions.8.id
```

etc etc...

In the above example, the number I am ULTIMATELY wanting to save in a variable is 10.

I want to return the highest number that appears in these tables, it can be 0-100000 (I doubt it) but it can't be hardcoded for example. It could only go up to 3!

I have the following code that basically takes whatever string you give it, and CORRECTLY extracts the number, which is great!

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100)
SET @string = 'cmi.interactions.10.id'
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string) <> 0

SET @string = STUFF(@string,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@string),1,'')

SELECT @string
```

Except I am not sure how to run this function across all the rows in the temp_table and to either replace each row with the highest number, or to return the highest number.

So either I need to figure out a way to return the highest number found in the table, or if you guys could help me by figuring out some way to UPDATE the temp_table, and replacing each string with the number found in it... I would be able to do the rest.

Comment: Just replace the fixed parts of the string with `''` then cast to int.

Comment: @shawnt00

Could you elaborate with some psuedo code by chance? I tried doing something like  UPDATE #temp_table SET SCORM_VARNAME = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SCORM_VARNAME)             but that didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @v = (
    select max(cast(replace(replace(s, 'cmi.interactions.', ''), '.id', '') as int))
    from T
);
```

Comment: Okay so I am getting a "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'cmi.interactions.0' to data type int.'      when I run your code.

When I remove the space that you have in the string:   cmi. interactions    I get the data back but its the exact same as it is found in the #temp_table

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I pretty much used your code with very little changes.... So you get the correct answer!!!! Nice one dude!

Comment: Yeah, that's my annoying phone keyboard adding spaces after every period. Not sure what you mean by same data.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer ... Just another option is `parsename()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SCORM_VARNAME] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('cmi.interactions.0.id')
,('cmi.interactions.1.id')
,('cmi.interactions.10.id')
,('cmi.interactions.5.id')
,('cmi.interactions.8.id')

Select *
      ,Value = try_convert(int,parsename(Scorm_Varname,2))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SCORM_VARNAME   Value
cmi.interactions.0.id   0
cmi.interactions.1.id   1
cmi.interactions.10.id  10
cmi.interactions.5.id   5
cmi.interactions.8.id   8
```

**For the MAX**

```
Select Value = max(try_convert(int,parsename(Scorm_Varname,2)))
 From  @YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional input!